# Error al compilar en c++

Tags: c++

El error al compilar es  ''undefined reference to ' calcularArea()' ''
   Esta en formato cpp y editado con codeblocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int calcularArea();

int main()
{
  float lado1,lado2,angulo,angulor,pi;
  pi=3.1415;

  cout << "Introduzca un lado del triangulo:";
  cin >> lado1;
  cout << "Introduzca otro lado del triangulo:";
  cin >> lado2;
  cout << "Introduzca un angulo:";
  cin >> angulo;
  angulor=((angulo*pi)/180);

  calcularArea();
  return 0;
 }

 int calcularArea(float lado1,float lado2, float angulor)
 {
   int area;
   area=((1/2)*lado1*lado2*angulor);
   return area;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabas de descubrir una cosa importante: **los argumentos de la función forman parte del nombre**. En otras palabras, `int calcularArea();` **no es lo mismo** que `int calcularArea( float, float, float );`

Aparte de eso, hay otro error: Si la función recibe **3 argumentos**, la tienes que llamar, justamente, con 3 argumentos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int calcularArea( float, float, float );

int main()
{
  float lado1,lado2,angulo,angulor,pi;
  pi=3.1415;

  cout << "Introduzca un lado del triangulo:";
  cin >> lado1;
  cout << "Introduzca otro lado del triangulo:";
  cin >> lado2;
  cout << "Introduzca un angulo:";
  cin >> angulo;
  angulor=((angulo*pi)/180);

  calcularArea( lado1, lado2, angulo );

  return 0;
 }

 int calcularArea(float lado1,float lado2, float angulor)
 {
   int area;
   area=((1/2)*lado1*lado2*angulor);
   return area;
 }
```